# FOSCommentBundle not ajax with posts limit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, foscommentbundle

I use this bundle https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

but need first comments display in html - not assync.
its almost done i create controller extends ThreadController

add function to get limited posts

```
public function getThreadCommentsWithLimitAction(Request $request, $id, $limit=false)
    {

        $displayDepth = $request->query->get('displayDepth');
        $sorter = $request->query->get('sorter');
        $thread = $this->container->get('fos_comment.manager.thread')->findThreadById($id);

        // We're now sure it is no duplicate id, so create the thread
        if (null === $thread) {
            // Decode the permalink for cleaner storage (it is encoded on the client side)
            $permalink = urldecode($request->query->get('permalink'));

            $thread = $this->container->get('fos_comment.manager.thread')
                ->createThread();
            $thread->setId($id);
            $thread->setPermalink($permalink);

            // Validate the entity
            $validator = $this->get('validator');
            $errors = $validator->validate($thread, 'NewThread');
            if (count($errors) > 0) {
                $view = View::create()
                    ->setStatusCode(Codes::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)
                    ->setData(array('errors' => $errors))
                    ->setTemplate(new TemplateReference('FOSCommentBundle', 'Thread', 'errors'));

                return $this->getViewHandler()->handle($view);
            }

            // Add the thread
            $this->container->get('fos_comment.manager.thread')->saveThread($thread);
        }

        $viewMode = $request->query->get('view', 'tree');

        switch ($viewMode) {
            case self::VIEW_FLAT:
                $comments = $this->container->get('fos_comment.manager.comment')->findCommentsByThread($thread, $displayDepth, $sorter);

                // We need nodes for the api to return a consistent response, not an array of comments
                $comments = array_map(function($comment) {
                    return array('comment' => $comment, 'children' => array());
                },
                    $comments
                );
                break;
            case self::VIEW_TREE:
            default:
                $comments = $this->container->get('fos_comment.manager.comment')->findCommentTreeByThread($thread, $sorter, $displayDepth);
                break;
        }

        $view = View::create()
            ->setData(array(
                'comments' => $comments,
                'displayDepth' => $displayDepth,
                'limit' => $limit,
                'sorter' => 'date',
                'thread' => $thread,
                'view' => $viewMode,
            ))
            ->setTemplate(new TemplateReference('FOSCommentBundle', 'Thread', 'comments'));

        // Register a special handler for RSS. Only available on this route.
        if ('rss' === $request->getRequestFormat()) {
            $templatingHandler = function($handler, $view, $request) {
                $view->setTemplate(new TemplateReference('FOSCommentBundle', 'Thread', 'thread_xml_feed'));

                return new Response($handler->renderTemplate($view, 'rss'), Codes::HTTP_OK, $view->getHeaders());
            };

            $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->registerHandler('rss', $templatingHandler);
        }

        return $this->getViewHandler()->handle($view);
    }
```

override template comments.html.twig

```
{% set depth = depth|default(0) %}
{% set view = view|default('tree') %}
{% if depth == 0 %}
    {% if fos_comment_can_comment_thread(thread) %}
        {% render url("fos_comment_new_thread_comments", {"id": thread.id}) %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if fos_comment_can_edit_thread(thread) %}
    <div class="fos_comment_thread_commentable">
        <button data-url="{{ url('fos_comment_edit_thread_commentable', {'id': thread.id, 'value': not thread.commentable}) }}" class="fos_comment_thread_commentable_action">
            {{ (thread.commentable ? 'fos_comment_thread_close' : 'fos_comment_thread_open') | trans({}, 'FOSCommentBundle') }}
        </button>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% set count = thread.numComments %}
    <h3>{% transchoice count with {'%count%': count} from "FOSCommentBundle" %}fos_comment_thread_comment_count{% endtranschoice %}</h3>
{% endif %}

{% if limit is defined and limit>0%}
    {% for commentinfo in comments|slice(0, limit) %}
        {% include "FOSCommentBundle:Thread:comment.html.twig" with { "children": commentinfo.children, "comment": commentinfo.comment, "depth": depth, "view": view } %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if comments|length > limit %}
        <p><a href="{{ path('place_one_commentsAll',{
                threadId: comments.0.comment.thread.id
            }) }}">zobacz wszystkie wypowiedzi ({{ comments|length }})</a></p>
    {% endif %}

{% else %}
    {% for commentinfo in comments %}
        {% include "FOSCommentBundle:Thread:comment.html.twig" with { "children": commentinfo.children, "comment": commentinfo.comment, "depth": depth, "view": view } %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I know for now i limit in twig is not finish yet but have ask fo js actions

Commens show coretly but actions (reply, add vote) not work.

I include manualy comments.js from fos https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/assets/js/comments.js

and manually setup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var fos_comment_thread_id = 'place{{ place.id }}';
                var fos_comment_thread_api_base_url = '{{ path('fos_comment_get_threads') }}';
            </script>
```

How i can initialize js actions ?

i try `FOS_COMMENT.initializeListeners();`

```
VM229:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: FOS_COMMENT is not defined(…)
```

js is loaded.

When i initialize in this way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var fos_comment_thread_id = 'place{{ place.id }}';
                var fos_comment_thread_api_base_url = '{{ path('fos_comment_get_threads') }}';
            </script>
            <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/comments.js') }}"></script>
```

i get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: FOS_COMMENT.thread_container.trigger is not a function
```